# Как сделать появления и скрытие элемента через определенное время?

Tags: javascript

Все привет. Вот сделал появление div блока по клику, при какой-то ошибке, он появляется через 0.5 секунд,  а как сделать, чтоб он появился на 0.5с и исчез через 5 секунд?

```
if(res.data == ""){
    setTimeout( () => {
        this.msg = !this.msg
        this.dangerInput = 'uk-form-danger'
    }, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(res.data == ""){
  setTimeout( () => {
    // появись
  }, 500);
  setTimeout( () => {
    // исчезни
  }, 5500);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(res.data == ""){
  setTimeout( () => {
    // появись
    setTimeout( () => {
      // исчезни
    }, 5000);
  }, 500);
}
```